# How to import python files from within a notebook when the files are in another directory?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I have a folder structure that looks like:

```
project/
    | Notebooks/
        | Notebook1.ipynb
        | Notebook2.ipynb
        
    | src/
        | __init__.py
        | utils.py
```

And in my notebooks I want to run

```
from utils import my_function
```

But of course that results in the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'
```

So far I found I could do this by first running

```
sys.path.insert(0, '../src/')
```

But that is breaking some functionality in VS code.

What is the right way to do this?

---

UPDATE:

I'm finding that running this in my notebooks:

```
path_to_package = os.path.abspath(os.path.join('..'))
if path_to_package not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path_to_package)
```

And then importing my code as

```
from src.utils import *
```

Is working much better. But still happy to learn of any "better" approaches.

Answer (score 0):

You can set $PYTHONPATH env variable, with the absolute path of the project or src directory, the syntax is the same as PATH.

Having PYTHONPATH=/absolute/path/to/src/ will allow

```py
from utils import *
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
from project.src.utils import *
```

Comment: no, I haven't, the project name is not a valid python package name.